# I am Wrote this python code but every time it's give me wrong answer

Tags: python

I have wrote this Code for calculates the product of the first natural numbers, but it showing answer 1 every time. I don't where i did mistake?? Can you please help me find out my mistake in this code..

```
num = 10

i = 0
prod = 1
while i<=num:
    i = i+1
    prod*prod*i

print(prod)
```

Comment: `prod*prod*i` doesn't do anything. Did you want `prod=prod*i`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be on the line `prod*prod*i`. The product needs to be accumulated and for this it should be exchanged for `prod*=i`.

The new snippet is:

```
num = 10
i = 0
prod = 1
while i<=num:
    print(i)
    i = i+1
    prod*=i

print(prod)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `prod*prod*i` write `prod=prod*i`

Answer (score 0):

Here we first take the input of the number of terms.Then we iterate the for loop and multiply the value of x with the initial value(=1).Then we assign the new value to p.

```
n=int(input('Terms: ')) #specifing the limit
p=1
for x in range(1,n+1):
    p=p*x
    print(p)
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Comment: I did not provide much details here cause I am assuming this thing to be very basic.But if needed I will update my answer

Comment: ok, it's just a recommendation